# How to solve character encoding issue with Emacs, mathematica.el, and Mathematica 10?

Tags: character-encoding

I am successfully using mathematica.el in Emacs with Mathematica 10. However, I have some kind of issue with character encoding whereby when I call mathematica-execute on a Mathematica expression the result prints lots of ^M characters to the output (I am running all processes on OS X Mavericks). I initially made sure that the $CharacterEncoding in Mathematica matched the file and process encoding of Emacs for the buffers being used as best I could: utf-8. There could still be an issue there, but that route didn't yield a solution. Next I thought, why not just create my own function that calls mathematica-execute and then removes the ^M characters from the resulting output. Here is the relevant code:

```
(defun delete-to-out ()
     (next-line)
     (set-mark-command nil)
     (search-forward "]=")
     (previous-line)
     (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end)))

(defun remove-^M ()
  "Get rid of ^M characters"
  (interactive)
  (message "remove-^M called!")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "\r" nil t)
      (replace-match ""))))

(defun my-mathematica-execute (arg)
  "Call mathematica-execute and then clean out the ^M characters
  it inserts by calling remove-^M"
  (interactive "P")
  (save-excursion
    (mathematica-execute arg)
    (remove-^M)
    ;; (delete-to-out)
    ))

;;; Define some mathematica mode keyboard bindings
(if mathematica-mode-map
    (progn
      (define-key mathematica-mode-map [remap mathematica-execute]
        'my-mathematica-execute)
      (define-key mathematica-mode-map (kbd "C-c m")
        'remove-^M)))
```

Calling my-mathematica-execute works, but isn't successful at removing the ^M characters. Calling remove-^M or delete-to-out work fine in isolation subsequently. It must be a synchronization issue or timing issue? Any help would be appreciated. Alternative solutions are certainly welcome.

Comment: possibly relevant http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/_005eM-in-the-shell-buffer.html also you might find more emacs experts on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Thanks @george2079, I am trying the suggestions mentioned at the link you provided. That was a good find. My Emacs shell doesn't have this problem, but since mathematica.el uses the command line this may be related. I especially think so since the input command gets echoed which is a symptom mentioned in the linked help page. So far the suggestions haven't solved the problem, but I may need to adjust a few things for the fact that my default shell is zsh, so I am working on that as a possibility amongst other things.

Comment: I was able to find an appropriate place to hack in a function called mathematica-filter which gets set as the process filter for the mathematica process output. There I inserted a replace-regexp-in-string call to get rid of all \r characters on the output string. That works. Now I just will tweak things a bit: it currently echoes the input to output (along with the result) and I may not want that. Typically that is due to the underlying shell echoing (since Mathematica is executing in the shell, zsh). ...

Comment: I'd like to solve that fundamental issue of having zsh not echo input to output in the Emacs->zsh->Mathematica->Emacs communication, but I'll use this hack until someone who knows better comes along and shows me a better way.

Comment: I was able to get my desired outcome: no ^M characters and no input echoing by hacking on mathematica-filter in two places. For those interested, here is a [link](https://gist.github.com/analyticd/de40d724975627673928#file-gistfile1-diff) to the diffs.

Comment: The gist linked in the previous comment is not quite perfect. I'll update when I get it fully situated. I am too aggressively trimming the echoed input and it is removing some of the output, e.g., the numerator of a fraction. This is easy to fix.

Comment: Well, it turned out that it is not so easy to eliminate the echoed input with a regex without also sometimes messing up the output due to the way results can vary. I decided I can live with the echoed input, just not the ^M characters and so the revised [gist](https://gist.github.com/analyticd/de40d724975627673928#file-gistfile1-diff) suffices for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be related to an encoding settings of intermediate shell between Emacs and mathematica kernel. Therefore a solution is to tell Emacs to communicate with mathematica kernel using pipes, not PTYs.

Specifically, in mathematica.el wrap the call to `start-process`
in setting `process-connection-type` to `NIL`

```
(let ((process-connection-type nil))                                
  (start-process                                                      
    (format "mathematica<%s>" (buffer-name workbuf))                   
    (format "*mathematica<%s>*" (buffer-name workbuf))                 
    mathematica-command-line)))
```